# Directory permissions to a php file

Tags: php, file, permissions, directory, chmod

I want to give directory permissions not to an user, but to a file which contains php code. Is it possible ?
something like chmod 777 directory_name -> file.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: You give rights TO a user FOR a file...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 755);   // decimal; probably incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", "u+rwx,go+rx"); // string; incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode
?>
```

here `/somedir/somefile` is your file path and read this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: The problem is not the path, I hoped I can somehow give permissions to a file not to an username. I think Nicky De Maeyer understand what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not give a specific **file** access to a path, only a **user** or a **usergroup**

you could maybe create a separate user and use it to execute the file.

Comment: Well.. I taught so, but I hoped for an alternative

Comment: What other user is going to be using the file? Maybe you are fixating on an impossible solution

Comment: I wanted to access some images only trough a php file, but I think I will try something else now :). Ty

Comment: I think it is best to update the question with your motive for doing this, as creepy eyes says: I think you are tackling the wrong problem.